# Cleaner JSX for React-Router Links

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm wondering if anyone has a better way of having a number of links that use React-Router's Link component. Here's what my code looks like:

```
<ul className="site-nav__list">
    <li className="site-nav__list-item">
        <Link
          className="site-nav__link"
          activeClassName="is-active"
          to={'/example'}
        >Example</Link>
    </li>
    <li className="site-nav__list-item">
        <Link
          className="site-nav__link"
          activeClassName="is-active"
          to={'/example'}
        >Example</Link>
    </li>
    <li className="site-nav__list-item">
        <Link
          className="site-nav__link"
          activeClassName="is-active"
          to={'/example'}
        >Example</Link>
    </li>
    <li className="site-nav__list-item">
        <Link
          className="site-nav__link"
          activeClassName="is-active"
          to={'/example'}
        >Example</Link>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Can you guys think of a better way of doing this, like looping over an array of Objects that has the name and the url? Seems like a good idea but I'm not sure how I'd go about writing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Stateless function components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#stateless-functions) are handy for cleaning up your `render()` methods when you have repetitive bits of static content:

```
let SiteNavLink = ({children, to}) => <li className="site-nav__list-item">
  <Link className="site-nav__link" activeClassName="is-active" to={to}>
    {children}
  </Link>
</li>
```

Usage:

```
<ul className="site-nav__list">
  <SiteNavLink to="/example1">Example 1</SiteNavLink>
  <SiteNavLink to="/example2">Example 2</SiteNavLink>
  <SiteNavLink to="/example3">Example 3</SiteNavLink>
  <SiteNavLink to="/example4">Example 4</SiteNavLink>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like...

Introduce a new component:

```
function MyLink({ url, title }) {
  return (
    <li className="site-nav__list-item">
      <Link
        className="site-nav__link"
        activeClassName="is-active"
        to={url}>
        {title}
      </Link>
    </li>
  )
}
```

Then create a collection to create (or source from a dynamic data source):

```
const urls = [
  { url: '/foo' title: 'Foo' },
  { url: '/bar' title: 'Bar' },
  { url: '/baz' title: 'Baz' },
];
```

Then render:

```
<ul className="site-nav__list">
  {
    urls.map(({ url, title }) => 
      <MyLink key={url} url={url} title={title} /> 
    )
  }
</ul>
```

Comment: Sorry, @JonnyBuchanan has an answer that came before mine that also recommends the stateless function. He would deserve the credit therefore for that idea as his was posted before mine.  I was typing away whilst he did so. :)